# Can I use a wildcard when setting dynamic template properties for elasticsearch index templates?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index template which has a property that has a dynamic object called meta.
I also have a dynamic templating rule which sets all the meta properties of type string to keyword and adds them to another field called catch_all.

There is a specific property, extendedDescription, that I don't want to be added as a keyword, I want to explicitly set it's type to text. I did that by adding an explicit setting for that setting.

However that property can appear within different parent properties in my meta object, for example within `"meta.none.extendedDescription"` or `"meta.it.extendedDescription"` or `"meta.en.extendedDescription"`.

This is what I'm using now, and *it works* but you can see I have to 'hardcode' the setting for each occurance of extendedDescription. (And play nice with the dynamic template I already have)

```
{
  "order": 0,
  "index_patterns": [
    "my-poi-*"
  ],
  "settings": {},
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields_all": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword",
              "type": "keyword",
              "copy_to": "catch_all"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": "catch_all"
        },
        "meta": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties": {
            "none": {
              "type": "object",
              "dynamic": true,
              "properties": {
                "extendedDescription": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "index": false
                }
              }
            },
            "it": {
              "type": "object",
              "dynamic": true,
              "properties": {
                "extendedDescription": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "index": false
                }
              }
            },
            "en": {
              "type": "object",
              "dynamic": true,
              "properties": {
                "extendedDescription": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "index": false
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "catch_all": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {}
}
```

Is there a way to use a wildcard or rule that would allow this property to be set to text no matter where in my meta object it appears? (It would always have the pattern of `"meta.{some-lang-code}.extendedDescription"`

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
"meta": {
  "type": "object",
  "dynamic": true,
  "properties": {
    "*.extendedDescription": {
      "type": "text",
          "index": false                            
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it while setting `dynamic: false` on the top level b/c that way you're preventing any unknown `meta.*` objects in advance. I could be wrong here but I think it's indeed the case.

You can try using `path_match` though:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "meta": {
            "path_match": "meta.*",          <--
            "mapping": {
              "type": "object",
              "dynamic": true,
              "properties": {
                "extendedDescription": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "index": false
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "string_fields_all": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword",
              "type": "keyword",
              "copy_to": "catch_all"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "dynamic": true,                     <--
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": "catch_all"
        },
        "catch_all": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```